Unable to replicate Twisted IFA antenna S-parameter curve using ANSYS HFSS 15
I am attempting to replicate the S-parameter curve for an antenna design as described in the paper "Antenna Design and Analysis" with DOI: 10.1109/LAWP.2009.2015345 using ANSYS HFSS 15.
Here are the specifics of my simulation setup:

Dimensions: All dimensions match those provided in the paper, including the substrate thickness.
Excitation Type: Lumped port.
Solution Type: Driven terminal.
Vias: Cylindrical.
Solution Frequency: Set to 3 GHz.
Passes: 4 passes with a maximum Delta S of 0.02.

Despite ensuring that all parameters are consistent with the paper, my simulated S-parameter curve does not match the results presented. I have checked the setup multiple times and ensured that all dimensions and material properties are correctly inputted.
What could be the possible reasons for this discrepancy? Are there any specific settings or considerations in ANSYS HFSS 15 that I might be overlooking? Any suggestions or guidance to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Here are the theoretical dimensions and S curve:

And my simulation results:

Note: I am very much a beginner in the RF field with very basic knowledge.
Here's the link to my HFSS 15 project file
